# Querying BigQuery Dataset from Django App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have data stored in BigQuery - it is a small dataset - roughly 500 rows. I want to be able to query this data and load it in to the front end of Django Application. What is the best practice for this type of data flow?

I want to be able to make calls to the BigQuery API using Javascript. I will then parse the result of the query and serve it in the webpage. The alternative seems to be to find a way of making a regular copy of the BigQuery data which I could store in a Cloud Storage Bucket but this adds a potentially unnecessary level of complexity which I could hopefully avoid if there is a way to query the live dataset.

Comment: best option would certainly be directly calling BigQuery from your application. I would suggest using node.js client library for BQ  and run your javascript code in node.js running environment (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs)

Comment: Thanks - what advantages would there be in doing it this way over using the python client library in Django?

Comment: I suggested node.js given that you wanted to use Javascript, but python library should not be any different; they call to the same end